# How to create Lomo / Retro effects in Android Camera Preview?

Tags: android, filter, effects, android-camera

Since Android 2.0 onwards, the camera API has supports few ColorEffect(s).

The list could be found here, from Effect Aqua onwards.
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html#EFFECT_AQUA

The effect could be implemented as follows:

```
Camera.Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();
parameters.setColorEffect(Camera.Parameters.EFFECT_AQUA);
camera.setParameters(parameters);
```

Apart from those supported effects, I am thinking to introduce Lomo or Retro effect in my application. Can anyone give some guidance on how to provide extra effects for the camera preview?

Code samples will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: In case anyone else stumbles upon this question in the future, the OP is not trying to add effects to the `setColorEffect()` roster. Rather, the OP is trying to manipulate preview images and apply hand-coded effects as part of the preview images getting on the screen.

Comment: Will it be helpful for you? [how-can-i-manipulate-the-camera-preview](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6478375/how-can-i-manipulate-the-camera-preview)

Answer (score 1):

Camera preview formats discussion from [android-developers group](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/c85e829ab209ceea/).