# android camera working after minimizing

Tags: android, camera, minimize

As you may notice, camera in android phones stops working when we minimize it (for example when we start a new application). My question is: Is there any way to create an app with android camera, which records even if we minimize it so it could be recording videos while we are doing something different on our phone? Or may be it is only possible if we create such camera without using MediaStore? If you share some links or code which might help me, I'll be grateful. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the answer to this is that one must use

```
public final void setPreviewTexture (SurfaceTexture surfaceTexture)

Added in API level 11
Sets the SurfaceTexture to be used for live preview. 
Either a surface or surface texture is necessary for preview, 
and preview is necessary to take pictures.
```

from https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html . And
from https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/SurfaceTexture.html :

```
The image stream may come from either camera preview or video decode. 
A SurfaceTexture may be used in place of a SurfaceHolder when specifying the 
output destination of a Camera or MediaPlayer object. Doing so will cause all the 
frames from the image stream to be sent to the SurfaceTexture object rather than 
to the device's display.
```

and I would really like to try this and send you some code, but I have no phone more recent than gingerbread, and this was introduced with honeycomb.

Using a `surface` associated with an Activity, `surfaceDestroyed` is called sometime between `onPause` and `onStop` when the Activity is being minimised, although, oddly, not when the phone is being put to sleep: [How SurfaceHolder callbacks are related to Activity lifecycle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11495842/how-surfaceholder-callbacks-are-related-to-activity-lifecycle/13671391#13671391) But I hope that a `surfaceTexture` is not destroyed in this way.

Comment: There is one problem, when I start android camera with my app, camera becomes opened as another application, so I can't control that android camera from my app. Or may be I overlooked something. Any ideas?

Comment: Ah, you must be sending an intent to the camera app. Sorry, I was referring to a complete standalone recording application, like the one on github at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13127914/android-focus-mode-continuous-video-and-capturing-preview-frames. I don't think the standard camera app will do what you want.

Comment: So I have to create my own camera? Any ideas how to start?

Comment: The app at github I referenced in the previous comment is a tiny standalone camera app that can take single or video pictures. It's designed for experimenting so there's nothing fancy there. You could change that to use a `SurfaceTexture`. Or you could wait a couple of weeks and ask again - Santa might be bringing a new phone :-)