# NullPointerException error for Camera Parameters

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, android-camera

I have the following code:

```
Line Code
 193 private Camera mCamera;
 <!-- NO CALLS TO mCamera HERE -->
 229 mCamera = Camera.open();
 230 Camera.Parameters p = mCamera.getParameters();
```

And when I run the application I get the following stacktrace:

```
04-08 20:56:45.330: E/AndroidRuntime(570): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-08 20:56:45.330: E/AndroidRuntime(570): java.lang.NullPointerException
04-08 20:56:45.330: E/AndroidRuntime(570):  at com.soloman.cbc.FullscreenActivity$MySurfaceView.surfaceCreated(FullscreenActivity.java:230)
04-08 20:56:45.330: E/AndroidRuntime(570):  at android.view.SurfaceView.updateWindow(SurfaceView.java:569)
04-08 20:56:45.330: E/AndroidRuntime(570):  at android.view.SurfaceView.access$000(SurfaceView.java:86)
04-08 20:56:45.330: E/AndroidRuntime(570):  at android.view.SurfaceView$3.onPreDraw(SurfaceView.java:174)
04-08 20:56:45.330: E/AndroidRuntime(570):  at android.view.ViewTreeObserver.dispatchOnPreDraw(ViewTreeObserver.java:680)
04-08 20:56:45.330: E/AndroidRuntime(570):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1842)
04-08 20:56:45.330: E/AndroidRuntime(570):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:989)
04-08 20:56:45.330: E/AndroidRuntime(570):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4351)
04-08 20:56:45.330: E/AndroidRuntime(570):  at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:749)
04-08 20:56:45.330: E/AndroidRuntime(570):  at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:562)
04-08 20:56:45.330: E/AndroidRuntime(570):  at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:532)
04-08 20:56:45.330: E/AndroidRuntime(570):  at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:735)
04-08 20:56:45.330: E/AndroidRuntime(570):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
04-08 20:56:45.330: E/AndroidRuntime(570):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
04-08 20:56:45.330: E/AndroidRuntime(570):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-08 20:56:45.330: E/AndroidRuntime(570):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
04-08 20:56:45.330: E/AndroidRuntime(570):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-08 20:56:45.330: E/AndroidRuntime(570):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-08 20:56:45.330: E/AndroidRuntime(570):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
04-08 20:56:45.330: E/AndroidRuntime(570):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
04-08 20:56:45.330: E/AndroidRuntime(570):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

The code I am using is from [How can I manipulate the camera preview?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6478375/how-can-i-manipulate-the-camera-preview)

I have the `CAMERA permission` in the `AndroidManifest.xml`, and all `imports` are accounted for. Does anyone have any suggestions on how to fix this error?

Thank you.

Comment: where are you trying to open the camera?
Inside surface created function?
If you can post the function  where you are calling this method it would be helpful to give an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On devices without back-facing camera `Camera.open()` returns `null`. Try `Camera.open(0)` to get front camera.

Comment: That might be it! I'm using a nexus 7 for testing, so no rear camera :'(

Answer (score 1):

if the android version is prior to 3.0 use the

`getHolder().setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);`