# Android Camera settiing contrast

Tags: android, camera, surfaceholder

I want to build an android module for capturing pictures, I want to add the possibility for adjusting contrast in real time on the preview image (without using NDK library)?

Comment: Give me the project for freelance work I will do this, this site is only to help you to solve the issue in the code, not the entire project.

Comment: Put some of your try out code then we can help you .

Comment: I'm just using the Camera class for Android, and I try to add a seekbBar to my layout for adjusting the contrast but i don't know what'is the proprety of the preview image that i can adjust.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I manipulate the camera preview?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6478375/how-can-i-manipulate-the-camera-preview)

Comment: Thanks fiddler, it's a helpfull link.