# Android Camera how to use LUT images for preview effects

Tags: android, image-processing, bitmap, android-camera

I found out that u can use to bitmaps in Android using LUT. Before I used to
[do it programatically](https://xjaphx.wordpress.com/2011/06/22/image-processing-brightness-over-image/) then I found out about LUTs. 
They can be used to edit bitmaps and apply some effects like filters just like the one you see on stock camera like mono,sepia,solarize,etc..

I am working along side an IOS dev and we're trying to create an app that has camera taking functionality and the goal for the camera functionality is:

1. apply the LUT filter to the result captured image
2. apply the LUT
   filter to the camera preview (to make it brighter and smoother -usually the face of the person).

For IOS this library [Ifttt Fast Camera](https://github.com/IFTTT/FastttCamera) helps to achieve the above goals. For Android I'm trying to do the same thing but having a hard time. There are libraries that show how to apply LUTs to bitmaps but I can't find any resource for applying it to the camera preview.

The question/problem here is how to apply the LUT image/bitmap to Android camera preview or is it possible? If you guys have other approaches for achieving the goals please let me know too.

Sources that show LUT to edit the bitmap

- https://github.com/RenderScript/RsLutDemo
- https://github.com/dntks/easyLUT/wiki

References:

- https://xjaphx.wordpress.com/2011/06/22/image-processing-brightness-over-image/
- https://github.com/IFTTT/FastttCamera

Comment: @Piglet I fixed the links you can check it again.

Comment: You cannot smooth an image using LUTs which leaves us with how to apply a LUT to the camera preview. You already know how to implement a LUT which reduces your question to a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6478375/how-can-i-manipulate-the-camera-preview

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I manipulate the camera preview?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6478375/how-can-i-manipulate-the-camera-preview)

Comment: @Piglet the other link is good but doesn't directly talk about the application of LUT images/bitmap to the camera preview, though got some info on how to alter the preview by doing some changes to the raw data. Thanks.

Comment: as I said you already know how to apply a LUT on an image as you posted several links to respecitve code. the only piece you were missing was how to alter the preview image which is explained in the answer to that question. I think you can take that small step alone. if not, come back and ask a new more specific question. it might also not hurt if you find out what a LUT actually is. the fact that you want to smooth images with it shows that you don't have a clue...

Comment: @Piglet yes that is why I am asking cos this is new to me, I'll get more idea about the LUT too. From the link you provided I got some idea on how to apply and change the preview image and now I am trying to do that. If I get it I will post my answer here also for reference. Thanks.

Comment: applying a LUT is nothing but replacing values in an image. you look up what value to use for which original value in the Look Up Table. Image-processing doesn't get much easier :)

Comment: @Piglet the links you shared has nothing to do with the question, they talk about a very general idea of the camera manipulation. I think this question is really important and I am really having the same difficulties right now unfortunately :(